# Intermittent HTTP request timeouts timeouts with ECS Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc, aws-fargate

I am working on deploying my application on AWS ECS Fargate.

Got to the point when I have two working CloudFormation templates. The first template creates a network VPC. The second defines the rest of my infrastructure including the Application Load Balancer, Target Groups, Fargate Cluster and Service running the Containers.

My service seems to be working OK, to the point that the probes never fail. My containers are not being deregistered and there is no draining. However, many of the requests sent to my load-balancer time-out, or take a long-time to complete. While others return very quickly and response codes are always 20X. There is no evidence of timeouts anywhere in logs either.

Below is my network VPC configuration:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: >
  Creates a VPC with public and private subnets for a given AWS Account.
  This template incorporates many design ideas from this excellent blog post:
    https://medium.com/aws-activate-startup-blog/practical-vpc-design-8412e1a18dcc#.g0txo2p4v

Parameters:
  VpcCidrParam:
    Type: String
    Description: VPC CIDR. For more info, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Subnets.html#VPC_Sizing
    AllowedPattern: "^(10|172|192)\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\/(16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28)$"
    ConstraintDescription: must be valid IPv4 CIDR block (/16 to /28) from the private address ranges defined in RFC 1918.

  # Public Subnets
  PublicAZASubnetBlock:
    Type: String
    Description: Subnet CIDR for first Availability Zone
    AllowedPattern: "^(10|172|192)\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\/(16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28)$"
    ConstraintDescription: must be valid IPv4 CIDR block (/16 to /28) from the private address ranges defined in RFC 1918.

  PublicAZBSubnetBlock:
    Type: String
    Description: Subnet CIDR for second Availability Zone
    AllowedPattern: "^(10|172|192)\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\/(16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28)$"
    ConstraintDescription: must be valid IPv4 CIDR block (/16 to /28) from the private address ranges defined in RFC 1918.

  PublicAZCSubnetBlock:
    Type: String
    Description: Subnet CIDR for third Availability Zone
    AllowedPattern: "^(10|172|192)\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\/(16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28)$"
    ConstraintDescription: must be valid IPv4 CIDR block (/16 to /28) from the private address ranges defined in RFC 1918.

  # Private Subnets
  PrivateAZASubnetBlock:
    Type: String
    Description: Subnet CIDR for first Availability Zone (e.g. us-west-2a, us-east-1b)
    AllowedPattern: "^(10|172|192)\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\/(16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28)$"
    ConstraintDescription: must be valid IPv4 CIDR block (/16 to /28) from the private address ranges defined in RFC 1918.

  PrivateAZBSubnetBlock:
    Type: String
    Description: Subnet CIDR for second Availability Zone (e.g. us-west-2b, us-east-1c)
    AllowedPattern: "^(10|172|192)\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\/(16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28)$"
    ConstraintDescription: must be valid IPv4 CIDR block (/16 to /28) from the private address ranges defined in RFC 1918.

  PrivateAZCSubnetBlock:
    Type: String
    Description: Subnet CIDR for third Availability Zone, (e.g. us-west-2c, us-east-1d)
    AllowedPattern: "^(10|172|192)\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\/(16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28)$"
    ConstraintDescription: must be valid IPv4 CIDR block (/16 to /28) from the private address ranges defined in RFC 1918.

  HighlyAvailableNat:
    Type: String
    Description: Optional configuration for a highly available NAT Gateway setup. Default configuration is a single NAT Gateway in Subnet A. The highly available option will configure a NAT Gateway in each of the Subnets.
    AllowedPattern: "^(true|false)$"
    Default: "false"
    ConstraintDescription: must be true or false (case sensitive).

Conditions:
  HighlyAvailable: !Equals [!Ref HighlyAvailableNat, "true"]
  NotHighlyAvailable: !Equals [!Ref HighlyAvailableNat, "false"]
Outputs:
  VpcId:
    Description: VPC Id
    Value: !Ref Vpc
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-vpc-id"

  PublicRouteTableId:
    Description: Route Table for public subnets
    Value: !Ref PublicRouteTable
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-public-rtb"

  PublicAZASubnetId:
    Description: Availability Zone A public subnet Id
    Value: !Ref PublicAZASubnet
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-public-az-a-subnet"

  PublicAZBSubnetId:
    Description: Availability Zone B public subnet Id
    Value: !Ref PublicAZBSubnet
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-public-az-b-subnet"

  PublicAZCSubnetId:
    Description: Availability Zone C public subnet Id
    Value: !Ref PublicAZCSubnet
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-public-az-c-subnet"

  PrivateAZASubnetId:
    Description: Availability Zone A private subnet Id
    Value: !Ref PrivateAZASubnet
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-private-az-a-subnet"

  PrivateAZBSubnetId:
    Description: Availability Zone B private subnet Id
    Value: !Ref PrivateAZBSubnet
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-private-az-b-subnet"

  PrivateAZCSubnetId:
    Description: Availability Zone C private subnet Id
    Value: !Ref PrivateAZCSubnet
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-private-az-c-subnet"

  PrivateAZARouteTableId:
    Description: Route table for private subnets in AZ A
    Value: !Ref PrivateAZARouteTable
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-private-az-a-rtb"

  PrivateAZBRouteTableId:
    Description: Route table for private subnets in AZ B
    Value: !Ref PrivateAZBRouteTable
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-private-az-b-rtb"

  PrivateAZCRouteTableId:
    Description: Route table for private subnets in AZ C
    Value: !Ref PrivateAZCRouteTable
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-private-az-c-rtb"

Resources:
  Vpc:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref VpcCidrParam
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}

  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}

  VPCGatewayAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc

  # Public Subnets - Route Table
  PublicRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-public
        - Key: Type
          Value: public

  PublicSubnetsRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
    DependsOn: VPCGatewayAttachment

  # Public Subnets
  # First Availability Zone
  PublicAZASubnet:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      CidrBlock: !Ref PublicAZASubnetBlock
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [0, !GetAZs ""]
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub
            - ${AWS::StackName}-public-${AZ}
            - { AZ: !Select [0, !GetAZs ""] }
        - Key: Type
          Value: public

  PublicAZASubnetRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicAZASubnet
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable

  # Second Availability Zone
  PublicAZBSubnet:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      CidrBlock: !Ref PublicAZBSubnetBlock
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [1, !GetAZs ""]
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub
            - ${AWS::StackName}-public-${AZ}
            - { AZ: !Select [1, !GetAZs ""] }
        - Key: Type
          Value: public

  PublicAZBSubnetRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicAZBSubnet
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable

  # Third Availability Zone
  PublicAZCSubnet:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      CidrBlock: !Ref PublicAZCSubnetBlock
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [2, !GetAZs ""]
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub
            - ${AWS::StackName}-public-${AZ}
            - { AZ: !Select [2, !GetAZs ""] }
        - Key: Type
          Value: public

  PublicAZCSubnetRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicAZCSubnet
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable

  # Private Subnets - NAT Gateways
  # First Availability Zone
  AZANatGatewayEIP:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc
    DependsOn: VPCGatewayAttachment

  AZANatGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt AZANatGatewayEIP.AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicAZASubnet

  # Second Availability Zone
  AZBNatGatewayEIP:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    Condition: HighlyAvailable
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc
    DependsOn: VPCGatewayAttachment

  AZBNatGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Condition: HighlyAvailable
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt AZBNatGatewayEIP.AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicAZBSubnet

  # Third Availability Zone
  AZCNatGatewayEIP:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    Condition: HighlyAvailable
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc
    DependsOn: VPCGatewayAttachment

  AZCNatGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Condition: HighlyAvailable
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt AZCNatGatewayEIP.AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicAZCSubnet

  # Private Subnets
  # First Availability Zone
  PrivateAZASubnet:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      CidrBlock: !Ref PrivateAZASubnetBlock
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [0, !GetAZs ""]
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub
            - ${AWS::StackName}-private-${AZ}
            - { AZ: !Select [0, !GetAZs ""] }
        - Key: Type
          Value: private

  PrivateAZARouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub
            - ${AWS::StackName}-private-${AZ}
            - { AZ: !Select [0, !GetAZs ""] }
        - Key: Type
          Value: private

  PrivateAZARoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateAZARouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref AZANatGateway

  PrivateAZARouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateAZASubnet
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateAZARouteTable

  # # Second Availability Zone
  PrivateAZBSubnet:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      CidrBlock: !Ref PrivateAZBSubnetBlock
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [1, !GetAZs ""]
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub
            - ${AWS::StackName}-private-${AZ}
            - { AZ: !Select [1, !GetAZs ""] }
        - Key: Type
          Value: private

  PrivateAZBRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub
            - ${AWS::StackName}-private-${AZ}
            - { AZ: !Select [1, !GetAZs ""] }
        - Key: Type
          Value: private

  PrivateAZBRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Condition: HighlyAvailable
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateAZBRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref AZBNatGateway

  PrivateAZBRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Condition: HighlyAvailable
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateAZBSubnet
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateAZBRouteTable

  NotHighlyAvailablePrivateAZBRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Condition: NotHighlyAvailable
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateAZBRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref AZANatGateway

  NotHighlyAvailablePrivateAZBRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Condition: NotHighlyAvailable
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateAZBSubnet
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateAZBRouteTable

  # Third Availability Zone
  PrivateAZCSubnet:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      CidrBlock: !Ref PrivateAZCSubnetBlock
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [2, !GetAZs ""]
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub
            - ${AWS::StackName}-private-${AZ}
            - { AZ: !Select [2, !GetAZs ""] }
        - Key: Type
          Value: private

  PrivateAZCRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub
            - ${AWS::StackName}-private-${AZ}
            - { AZ: !Select [2, !GetAZs ""] }
        - Key: Type
          Value: private

  PrivateAZCRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Condition: HighlyAvailable
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateAZCRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref AZCNatGateway

  PrivateAZCRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Condition: HighlyAvailable
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateAZCSubnet
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateAZCRouteTable
  
  NotHighlyAvailablePrivateAZCRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Condition: NotHighlyAvailable
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateAZCRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref AZANatGateway

  NotHighlyAvailablePrivateAZCRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Condition: NotHighlyAvailable
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateAZCSubnet
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateAZCRouteTable


  S3VPCEndpoint:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint"
    Properties:
      RouteTableIds:
        - !Ref PublicRouteTable
        - !Ref PrivateAZARouteTable
        - !Ref PrivateAZBRouteTable
        - !Ref PrivateAZCRouteTable
      ServiceName: !Join
        - ""
        - - com.amazonaws.
          - !Ref "AWS::Region"
          - .s3
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc

  DynamoDBVPCEndpoint:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint"
    Properties:
      RouteTableIds:
        - !Ref PublicRouteTable
        - !Ref PrivateAZARouteTable
        - !Ref PrivateAZBRouteTable
        - !Ref PrivateAZCRouteTable
      ServiceName: !Join
        - ""
        - - com.amazonaws.
          - !Ref "AWS::Region"
          - .dynamodb
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
```

My ECS+Fargate+ALB template, however, only uses two (2) subnets.

Could it be that I am having problems because my network template describes six (6) interfaces, while my cluster uses two (2) subnets?

Where should I be looking, if that is not the likely cause?

Comment: Farget + ALB template is not shown, but can you double check that ALB uses exactly same subnets as your fargate service? If one is different, it could explain why your requests sometimes fail, and sometimes work.

Comment: The template uses `Ref`. I slightly changed one found at https://github.com/1Strategy/fargate-cloudformation-example/blob/master/fargate.yaml

Since everything is defined within one file, probably interfaces among those are in sync.

Comment: I see. When you choose `SubnetA` and `SubnetB` for this template, are you sure you are using two  public subnets, not one private? ALB can't be in private.

Comment: just checked, and believe that you are correct. By mistake, I used one public and one private interface. overwhelming amount of information. i only used lambda and cloudwatch, until now. thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear. If you don't mind I will provide an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused most likely by registering ALB with **one public and one private subnet**. However, for ALB to work, it must be set in **two public subnets**.

Comment: After weeks of searching, this was the fix I was looking for. Both subnets need to be attached to route tables that route to an Internet Gateway (igw).